# Finding new observations per grouping in R

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a dataframe:

```
id = c('a', 'b', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd')
period = c(1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3)
a <- data.frame(period, id); a


  period  id
1      1  a
2      1  b
3      2  a
4      2  b
5      2  c
6      3  a
7      3  b
8      3  c
9      3  d
```

Now, I want find new observations per period. So I do,

```
a_group <- a %>% group_by(period) %>% count(id_count = n())
a_news <- a_group %>% ungroup() %>% 
  mutate(new_vals = id_count - lag(id_count))
a_news

       period id_count n new_vals
   <dbl>    <int> <int>    <int>
1      1        2     2       NA
2      2        3     3        1
3      3        4     4        1
```

This works fine, since for every period there is *one new unique* observation being added. Consider, when the *new* id per period is *not unique*:

```
id1 = c('a', 'b', 'a', 'b', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'a')
period1 = c(1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3)
b <- data.frame(period1, id1); b  

   period1 id1
1       1   a
2       1   b
3       2   a
4       2   b
5       2   a
6       3   a
7       3   b
8       3   c
9       3   a
b_group <- b %>% group_by(period1) %>% count(id1_count = n())
b_news <- b_group %>% ungroup() %>% 
  mutate(new_vals = id1_count - lag(id1_count))
```

I get the same result as `a_news`

```
   period1 id1_count     n new_vals        
1       1         2     2       NA
2       2         3     3        1
3       3         4     4        1
```

While in fact the *new* observation *a* is not new at all from period 2 onwards. How can I find out the count of new observations per period (after period 1)? Since, in period 1 of course everything is new.

Expected output for dataframe b:

```
period1 new_vals        
1      2
2      0
3      1
```

Where in period1 == 2, there is no new observation, in period1 == 3 there is one new observation (c)

Comment: What is the expected output?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try `Reduce` with `unique`:

```
tt <- split(a$id, a$period) #Split id per period
#Find unique id's until period
n <- lengths(Reduce(function(i,j) unique(c(i,j)), tt, accumulate = TRUE))
setNames(diff(c(0,n)), names(tt))
#1 2 3 
#2 1 1 

tt <- split(b$id1, b$period1)
n <- lengths(Reduce(function(i,j) unique(c(i,j)), tt, accumulate = TRUE))
setNames(diff(c(0,n)), names(tt))
#1 2 3 
#2 0 1
```

Comment: Sorry, it works now. Something was wrong in my R session I guess. Can you please explain what you did?

Comment: I have added some comments and hopefully simplified the method.

Comment: The important part is in `Reduce` where `unique` id's are cumulative (per period) returned.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a base R option using `aggregate` + `Vectorize` + `setdiff`

```
within(
  u <- aggregate(. ~ period1, b, c),
  newVar <- c(NA, lengths(Vectorize(setdiff)(id1[-1], id1[-nrow(u)])))
)
```

which gives

```
  period1        id1 newVar
1       1       a, b     NA
2       2    a, b, a      0
3       3 a, b, c, a      1
```

Comment: This works. Can you please explain what is happening? I do not understand the ```c``` argument in aggregate for instance. Thanks

Comment: @Kay `c` is to concatenate the values in `id1` (grouped by `period1`)

Comment: and could you please explain the second part with ```newVar```, what is it doing?

Comment: @Kay I run `setdiff` over `id1` to see the difference between adjacent rows, e.g., row 1 vs. row 2, and row 2 vs. row 3. I used `Vectorize` over `setdiff` since it allows me to run `setdiff(x,y)` with respect to two set lists `x` and `y`, where `x` here is a list of row 1 and row 2 in `id1`, and  `y` is a list of row 2 and row 3 in `id1`,

Comment: I see. I guess I have to read all these functions to understand them

Comment: Both yours and GKi's answers work for me and are equally explained. Although I do not understand both at my level

Answer (score 1):

One `dplyr` and `purrr` solution could be:

```
b %>%
 mutate(new_vals = pmax(row_number() == 1,
                        map_lgl(seq_along(id1), 
                                ~ !id1[.x] %in% unique(id1[1:(.x - 1)])))) %>%
 group_by(period1) %>%
 summarise(count = n(),
           id_count = n_distinct(id1),
           new_vals = sum(new_vals))

  period1 count id_count new_vals
    <dbl> <int>    <int>    <int>
1       1     2        2        2
2       2     3        2        0
3       3     4        3        1
```

Comment: I replaced ```a``` with ```b``` variables (since b is the problem).
```b %>%
  mutate(new_vals = (period1 > 1) * map_lgl(seq_along(id1), ~ !id1[.x] %in% unique(id1[1:(.x - 1)]))) %>%
  group_by(period1) %>%
  summarise(count = n(), id_count = n_distinct(id1), new_vals = sum(new_vals))```
The column new_vals is overall 0

Comment: can you please explain what is happening? I have never encountered the functions you use in ```mutate``` part

Answer (score 1):

You can do the trick by simply using the `unique` function:

```
    a_group <- unique(a) %>% count(period)
    a_group <- cbind(a_group,new_vals = diff(c(0,a_group$n)))

      period n new_vals
1      1     2    2
2      2     2    0
3      3     3    1
```